# How can a powersupply have a large input volt range

Tags: power-supply, computer-architecture, computers

I see that computer power supplies that can take a voltage input of anything between 90V and 260V at a frequency between 47Hz and 63Hz.

Meanwhile it can output power at a very precise voltage.

How does that work?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is done by magic ;-) Just kidding, it is not. It may look like a big deal but it's not actually. See the other answers, they are also correct.

The power from the mains is actually converted into MAGnetIC energy (do you see what I did there ;-) )and then back to electrical energy. Using very fast switches at the high voltage side the amount of energy that is transferred to the low voltage side can be precisely controlled. This conversion to magnetic energy also has the advantage that the output can be isolated from the mains supply so that you do NOT get an electrical shock when touching the output, I consider this is a very nice feature !

A reference voltage is made internally in the power supply's chip(s). Generating such a stable reference voltage is done using a [bandgap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bandgap_voltage_reference) circuit. The output voltage is compared to this reference voltage and adjusted so that it will be the correct voltage, this is called feedback. This feedback controls the circuit on the mains (high) voltage side and tells it to put more or less magnetic energy in the high frequency transformer depending on what the output voltage is doing. If the output voltage is too low: more ! If it is too high: less ! Simple as that. This feedback signal usually travels through an optocoupler (so using light) so that it does not need a direct wired connection to the mains side electronics and so keeping the isolation from the mains voltage side.

Due to this feedback the input voltage can vary over a wide range while the output voltage remains constant. Brilliant isn't it ? ;-)

Comment: +1 because of mentioning the reference voltage which is the key part (in my opinion) to generate a constant voltage. Maybe it could be added, that even with input voltage variations the output of the reference remains (mostly) constant.

Comment: Sure, let's do that :-)

Comment: Can't give you another +1 :-(

Answer (score 1):

Computer power supplies are [switch mode power supplies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Switched-mode_power_supply). In input voltage is chopped up and switched on and off rapidy (usually in the tens of kilohertz range). There is control circuitry that measures the output voltage and adjusts the amount of switching to compensate. Computer power supplies are designed to accommodate a large range and frequency so that they can work anywhere in the world.

Answer (score 0):

Typically the input AC is converted to a DC voltage, and the DC voltage is then converted to the desired output voltages by DC-DC converters.

Answer (score 0):

There are often 2 stages in a full range PSU.
The first stage rectifies the input to DC then steps it up to a higher DC voltage like 450Vdc which is above the max input voltage at peak.
This stage also takes care to maintain correct power factor which is required in most countries (makes the PSU behave more like a resistor that loads the whole sine wave and not only it's peaks).
The advantage of converting the input to a fixed high voltage is that the output conversion can be made more stable and simple with higher efficiency.